# Performing synthetic division on the reciprocal of a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the function $f(x)= \frac{3x-2}{x^3-3x^2+4}$.

I want to factor the denominator of $f$ using synthetic division.

Can I perform: 
$$\frac{1}{\frac{x^3-3x^2+4}{3x-2}}$$ 
then perform synthetic division, and then take the reciprocal of that answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. The polynomial $x^3-3x^2+4$ has a zero at $x=-1$ which means that it can be divided by $(x+1)$.

In order to factorize a polynomial $P(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1 x+a_0$ with integer coefficients, check if there is some integer root among the divisors of $a_0$. In fact if $P(d)=0$ and $d$ is non-zero integer then
$$0=P(d)=(d^{n-1}+a_{n-1}d^{n-2}+\dots+a_1)d+a_0.$$
Since $d$ divides $0$ then $d$ divides also the right-hand side which is an integer multiple of $d$ plus $a_0$. Hence $d$ divides $a_0$.

Comment: Thanks! I can see now that the denominator can be factored as $(x+1)(x-2)^2$. I'm still curious as to whether the method I proposed is a valid method for performing synthetic division, or is it an illegal operation.

Comment: It is not illegal but it not useful here. After the division you can write $x^3-3x^2+4=q(x)(3x-2)+r(x)$ but if  the remainder $r(x)$ is not zero you can not simplify your fraction.